# Calculate width available for columns in dataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

My question is very simple -  after data binding I want to set all columns width so that it will not be horizontal scrolling. Something like this:

```
    columnWidth = grid.width/grid.Columns.Count
```

But this expression does not consider the "left part of gridView" with which I can select row, which displays current row. How can I calculate its width? [(grid.width - X)/grid.Columns.Count]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy to do this.  Just set the [DataGridView.AutoSizeColumnMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autosizecolumnsmode.aspx) property to `Fill`.

```
grid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
```

And you may need to explicitly ask the grid to resize column spacing.  I can't remember for sure.  But that is simple to do:

```
grid.AutoResizeColumns();
```

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewautosizecolumnsmode.aspx), `Fill` will do the following:

> The column widths adjust so that the widths of all columns exactly
>   fill the display area of the control, requiring horizontal scrolling
>   only to keep column widths above the DataGridViewColumn.MinimumWidth
>   property values. Relative column widths are determined by the relative
>   DataGridViewColumn.FillWeight property values.

So basically, as long as you don't have any columns with a `MinimumWidth` that will prevent it, this property does exactly what you are looking for.

**EDIT:  Addressing the comment of the OP:**

You can always create a simple property to report that information to you.  Something like...

```
public int DataGridViewDeadSpaceWidth
{
    get
    {
        int x = grid.Width;
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in grid.Columns)
            x -= column.Width;

        return x;
    }
}
```

You could also use this to inherit from a `DataGridView` and add the property yourself to the control.  Note that there is probably some other dead space from the borders of the `DataGridView` that you need to account for.

Comment: it is all good.But if sometime I need to know this value?How can I achive it without doing reverse operation: X = size - columnWidth*Count ?